# Plot Dataset with Two Lines

Tags: dataset

I would like to plot a dataset with ListLinePlot (or similar opcodes).

As you can see, the frequencies are associated with both a minimum and maximum value. I would like to plot min and max values with two different lines. Values on y axes should be logarithmic or scaled since I need to show small differences based on the desired value of 1; otherwise, lines will appear too flat.
Would you please help me out?

freq = frequencies in Hz

```
Dataset[{
   <|"freq" -> "20", "min" -> {0.304667} , "max" -> {1.695337}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "25", "min" -> {0.419062} , "max" -> {1.581069}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "31", "min" -> {0.545485} , "max" -> {1.461269}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "40", "min" -> {0.700777} , "max" -> {1.299225}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "50", "min" -> {0.823792} , "max" -> {1.176197}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "63", "min" -> {0.923041} , "max" -> {1.076953}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "80", "min" -> {0.987322} , "max" -> {1.012541}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "100", "min" -> {0.986196}, "max" -> {1.013805}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "125", "min" -> {0.984422} , "max" -> {1.015579}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "160", "min" -> {0.996728} , "max" -> {1.0033288}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "200", "min" -> {0.992164} , "max" -> {1.007867}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "250", "min" -> {0.988889} , "max" -> {1.011117}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "315", "min" -> {0.99493} , "max" -> {1.00509}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "400", "min" -> {0.994376} , "max" -> {1.005624}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "500", "min" -> {0.987637} , "max" -> {1.012363}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "630", "min" -> {0.988853} , "max" -> {1.01112}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "800", "min" -> {0.99791} , "max" -> {1.00209}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "1k", "min" -> {0.992195} , "max" -> {1.007808}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "1.25k", "min" -> {0.987353}, "max" -> {1.012647}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "1.6k", "min" -> {0.991475} , "max" -> {1.008524}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "2k", "min" -> {0.99872} , "max" -> {1.00122}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "2.5k", "min" -> {0.989744}, "max" -> {1.010257}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "3.15k", "min" -> {0.98775} , "max" -> {1.011977}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "4k", "min" -> {0.994932} , "max" -> {1.005069}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "5k", "min" -> {0.993979} , "max" -> {1.006021}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "6.3k", "min" -> {0.987331}, "max" -> {1.011587}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "8k", "min" -> {0.993713} , "max" -> {1.006287}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "10k", "min" -> {0.99109} , "max" -> {1.008916}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "12.5k", "min" -> {0.995323}, "max" -> {1.004675}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "16k", "min" -> {0.850816} , "max" -> {1.149209}|>,
   <|"freq" -> "20k", "min" -> {0.236113} , 
    "max" -> {1.764056}|>
   }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using `Dataset`.

```
ds = <your Dataset from the question>

dsNumeric = 
 ds[All, <|#, ("freq" -> StringReplace[#freq, "k" -> " * 1000"]), 
     "min" -> First@#min, "max" -> First@#max|> &][All, ToExpression]

{min, max} = Values@Normal@dsNumeric[All, {"freq", #}] & /@ {"min", "max"};

ListLogPlot[{min, max}, Joined -> True]
```

For both axes logarithmic

```
ListLogLogPlot[{min, max}, Joined -> True]
```

Answer (score 4):

First, turn your data into numbers that can be used.

```
thing = Dataset["your data"]
freq = Flatten[ToExpression@StringSplit[Normal@thing[All, "freq"], " "]] /. k -> 1000
min = Normal@thing[All, "min"] // Flatten
max = Normal@thing[All, "max"] // Flatten
```

Then create two seperate lists.

```
dataMin = Table[{freq[[i]], Log[min[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length@freq}];
dataMax = Table[{freq[[i]], Log[max[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length@freq}];
```

Plot

```
ListLinePlot[{dataMin, dataMax}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot2]

I generally stay away from Datasets, though I'm sure they have their place. I find plain arrays far easier to manipulate...Welcome to mathematica stack exchange, don't forget to mark correct answers with the checkmark beside the accepted answers so others can find something similar. I encourage you to read other posts, and answer questions if you can!

Comment: Thanks, you have been of great help.

Comment: How do I use Logarithmic scale on X axe? When working with musical frequencies energy is constant per octave. This is the code I'm using so far:

Comment: thing = Dataset[result];
freq = Flatten[
   ToExpression@StringSplit[Normal@thing[All, "freq"], " "]] /. 
  k -> 1000
min = Normal@thing[All, "min"] // Flatten;
max = Normal@thing[All, "max"] // Flatten;
dataMin = Table[{freq[[i]], min[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@freq}];
dataMax = Table[{freq[[i]], max[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@freq}];
ListLinePlot[{dataMin, dataMax}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> {.97, 1.03}, PlotLegends -> {"min", "max"}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]

Comment: @AlMastro you can make the X axis log, by adding a `Log[]` to the `freq[[i]]` like `Log[freq[[i]]]` keep in mind, this is the natural log, if you want base 10, you need `Log10[]`

Answer (score 1):

Additional ways to query dataset `ds`:

```
ds[ListLinePlot[Transpose@#, PlotRange -> All] &, 
 Thread[{ToExpression[#freq] /. k -> 1000, Flatten@{#min, #max}}] &]
```

[image]

```
Query[ListLinePlot[Transpose@#, PlotRange -> All] &, 
  Thread[{ToExpression[#freq] /. k -> 1000, Flatten@{#min, #max}}] &]@ds
```

> same picture

```
ds[ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose@#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All] &, 
 Thread[{ToExpression[#freq] /. k -> 1000, Flatten@{#min, #max}}] &]
```

[image]

```
Query[ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose@#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All] &, 
  Thread[{ToExpression[#freq] /. k -> 1000, Flatten@{#min, #max}}] &]@ds
```

> same picture

```
ds[StackedListPlot[Transpose@#, PlotRange -> All] &, 
 Thread[{ToExpression[#freq] /. k -> 1000, Flatten@{#min, #max}}] &]
```

[image]

```
Query[ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose@#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
       PlotLayout -> "Stacked", Filling -> Axis] &, 
  Thread[{ToExpression[#freq] /. k -> 1000, Flatten@{#min, #max}}] &]@ds
```

[image]

```
ds[BarChart[#[[All, All, 2]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked"] &, 
 Thread[{ToExpression[#freq] /. k -> 1000, Flatten@{#min, #max}}] &]
```

[image]

etc...